# Print DIV Content with CSS, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintElem(elem) {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }
    function Popup(data) {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'mydiv', 'height=550,width=750');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" media="print" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Here is my Javascript that prints the DIV and that works fine.  But my CSS isn't loading, I can tell because I did a test color of pink and it still isn't showing up.  Please help.  HEre is my CSS

```html
@media print {
    .mydiv {
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 18px;
        color:pink;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is being sent to `data` ?

Comment: Is there any HTML element with the class of `mydiv` that is being sent to `data`?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is most likely the fact that your CSS is trying to reference the NAME of the WINDOW and not any object within the WINDOW. Since we don't know what is being sent as `data` try this:

**change**

```
mywindow.document.write(data);
```

**to**

```
mywindow.document.write("<div class='mydiv'>" + data + "</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I did similar (in fact the same) task and did it as follow:

Open "Print Version" document (empty template) and in its onload event retrieve div I need from its parent.
Sample code:

```
<!-- parent doc -->
<input type="button" value="Printer Version" onclick="doIt()" />
<div id="divPrint" style="display:none;">
   <iframe id="frPrint"></iframe>
</div>
<script>
function doIt(){
   document.getElementById('divPrint').style.display = '';
   document.getElementById('frPrint').src = "print.html?a=" + Math.random();//to avoid caching
}
function getContent(){
   return document.getElementsById('divData').innerHTML;
}
</script>

<!--print.html -->
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var a = this.parent.getContent();
        document.body.innerHTML = a;
    }
    function printMe() {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .right
    {
        float: right;
    }
</style>
<link href="/Styles/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant see in your code the reference to the class that link your `CSS` with the `Html tag`, try something like that:

```
mywindow.document.write('</head><body><div class="mydiv">');
mywindow.document.write(data);  
mywindow.document.write('</div></body></html>');
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`@media print` only works when you simple call window.print() function. 
        Here what you are doing is creating popup and inside it you are 
placing your html.
        So you have to include all css like below way. 
        Refer my below code.

```js
$(".printtt").on("click",function(e){ 
                var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
                                    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
                                    //mywindow.document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/bootstrap.min.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"print\" />");
                                    //mywindow.document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/sb-admin.css\" type=\"text/css\"  />");
    mywindow.document.write('<style>.printtt{color:pink;}</style>');
                                    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
                                    mywindow.document.write($("#page-wrapper").html());
                                    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                    
    setTimeout(function () {
                            mywindow.print();
                        },1000);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="aaaaa">
    </div>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="printtt">Print</a>
    </div>
```